# HTTP Interceptor not waiting for token to be refreshed before sending next request

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using Ionic 3 & Angular 5.

I am having trouble implementing a HTTP interceptor that refreshes my token if its expiring soon and sends the next request with the new token. The problem is that its not waiting for the refresh token to be updated before making the request. How can I fix this?

AuthService

```
refreshToken(token?: string) {
return this.http.get(`${this.API_URL}/refresh`)
  .pipe(catchError(this.handleServerError));
}
```

TokenInterceptor

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    // If the next request is to my refresh endpoint allow it through
    if (URL == `${this.globals.APIURL}/refresh`) {
        return request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                  Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                }
              });
    }
    // Else check if token is expiring soon and refresh it and send the new token in the request
    else {
      const expirationLeft = this.authService.getTokenExpiration();
      if (token && expirationLeft < (this.offsetSeconds * 1000) && !this.isUpdating) {
        this.isUpdating = true;
        try {
          this.authService.refreshToken(token)
            .subscribe(data =>
            {
              token = data.token;
              this.authService.storeToken(token);
              this.authService.authenticationNotifier().next(true);
              const clone = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                  Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                }
              });
              this.isUpdating = false;
              return next.handle(clone);

            },
            (err) =>
            {
              this.authService.logout();
              this.isUpdating = false;
            });
        }
        catch (e) {

        }
    }
    return request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          'Accept': 'application/json',
        }
      });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This code should be rewritten completely. Because I don't know which operations you actually need in your code, I can't rewrite it. But there a few things that can help you. First of all return Observable from intercept not Request.

```
return next.handle(req.clone({
    setHeaders: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    }
}));
```

in your 'else' case

```
this.updating = true;
return this.authService.refreshToken(token).pipe(
       tap(data => {
           this.authService.storeToken(token);
           this.authService.authenticationNotifier().next(true);
           this.isUpdating = false;
       }),
       mergeMap(data => next.handle(req.clone({
           setHeaders: {
               Authorization: `Bearer ${data.token}`,
              'Accept': 'application/json',
           }
       }))),
       catchError(err => {
            this.authService.logout();
            this.isUpdating = false;
            return of('Error');
       })
);
```

I'd rather move all this refreshToken logic to AuthService. Create a `getToken` method in AuthService which returns token wrapped by observable and impletement everything about token and refreshToken there.Interceptor will be clean and just do its work - intercept. In that case all the code you need in interceptor will be

```
return this.authService.getToken().pipe(
    mergeMap(token=> next.handle(req.clone({
           setHeaders: {
               Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
              'Accept': 'application/json',
           }
    })))
);
```

No if/else condition, no multiple returns.

Comment: If I move the code to `getToken()` how do I return the token in the interceptor?

Comment: This doesn't work i'm getting this error `An error occurred TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`

Comment: Look at the last example, token is argument of mergeMap, so you always have access to it.

Comment: Do you know if this protects against bursts, where say 3 requests go out all at once, and all three need auth tokens?  Does that result in three token refreshes since each one determines it needs a refresh?  Or, does the interceptor block the other two requests until next.handle() is called?

Comment: No there is no blocking in this implementation. But considering it's just one thread then it means there is no way 3 requests go out at the same exact time, they should be consequent. So when calling `refreshToken` instead of sending immediate request and return it, you can check for some flag or something if the request for refresh token has been sent.If yes then just return the observable that's waiting for the result instead of creating new request.